# Python gives name error for already defined

Tags: python, exception

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
browser.get('https://www.gradebeam.com/constructionresources/constructioncommunity.aspx?Category=Subs')
tablebodies = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.rpLink.rpExpandable')

print(len(tablebodies))
for row in tablebodies:
    CompanyName = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='rpOut']/span[2]").text
    rpslide = browser.find_element_by_class_name('rpSlide').find_elements_by_css_selector('.accountInfo')
    for list in rpslide:
        links = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[2]").text

    print(CompanyName , links)
```

The above code gives me a name error even though the links is defined already ........

if anyone could help would be really appreciated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
with open('E:\demo.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
with open('E:\Contractors1.csv', 'a') as f:
    headers = ("Company Name,Contact Person,Address,Event_Link,PhoneNumber,Faxnumber, Website")
    f.write(headers)
    f.write("\n")
    for link in content:
        browser.get(link)

        tablebodies = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.contentpaneopen.record-container')

        for row in tablebodies:
            try:
                CompanyName= row.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='title-container article-title pos-pagetitle item-pagetitle']/h2[1]/span[1]/a[1]/span[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                ContactPerson = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[1]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                Address1 = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[2]/div[1]").text
                Address = Address1.replace("\n","")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                PhoneNumber = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[4]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                Faxnumber = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[5]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                url = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='element element-sfobject element-last row2 elRow2']/div[1]/a[2]/").get_attribute('href')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            print(CompanyName.replace(",","|") + "," + ContactPerson.replace(",","|") + "," + Address.replace(',',"|") + "," + PhoneNumber + "," + Faxnumber +  "," + url + "\n")
```

This is one more similar code where i am able to print everything except the url it gives me the same name error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Aran-Fey below is snap of error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/testsad.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(CompanyName , links)
NameError: name 'links' is not defined

Comment: `rpslide` is empty.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51533021/edit) your question to include the *formatted error message*.

Comment: But in any event, where do you believe you defined `links`? I don't see it.

Comment: @user2357112 what could be the possible solution i want the name website email and address of the companies listed in the link

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/testsad.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(CompanyName , links)
NameError: name 'links' is not defined

Comment: @sachinsafale rps slide is empty

Comment: Same problem as I said it returns without url defined if the code in try part does,'t work, you have to define url in case of except as well so say url="didn't work" if it goes to except

Comment: @inder tried in except as well still gives the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176775/discussion-between-sachin-safale-and-inder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second part is returning error because url is returning empty but without an error, this should fix that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
with open('E:\demo.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
with open('E:\Contractors1.csv', 'a') as f:
    headers = ("Company Name,Contact Person,Address,Event_Link,PhoneNumber,Faxnumber, Website")
    f.write(headers)
    f.write("\n")
    for link in content:
        browser.get(link)

        tablebodies = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.contentpaneopen.record-container')

        for row in tablebodies:
            try:
                CompanyName= row.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='title-container article-title pos-pagetitle item-pagetitle']/h2[1]/span[1]/a[1]/span[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                ContactPerson = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[1]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                Address1 = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[2]/div[1]").text
                Address = Address1.replace("\n","")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                PhoneNumber = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[4]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                Faxnumber = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='introduction-container article-intro pos-intro item-intro']/div[5]/div[1]").text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            try:
                url = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='element element-sfobject element-last row2 elRow2']/div[1]/a[2]/").get_attribute('href')
                if url:
                    pass
                else:
                    url="url returned empty"
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
            print(CompanyName.replace(",","|") + "," + ContactPerson.replace(",","|") + "," + Address.replace(',',"|") + "," + PhoneNumber + "," + Faxnumber +  "," + url + "\n")
```

the changes i made:

in the last try there is an if condition that checks if url is empty so a:

```
if url:
```

returns true if the value of url is non empty other wise it jumps to else statement and define url as a string

Answer (score 2):

In your code here -

```
for row in tablebodies:
    CompanyName = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='rpOut']/span[2]").text
    rpslide = browser.find_element_by_class_name('rpSlide').find_elements_by_css_selector('.accountInfo')
    for list in rpslide:
        links = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[2]").text
    print(CompanyName , links)
```

You define `links` in the scope of`for list in rpslide` loop. But if `rpslide` is empty, `links` won't be declared at all.

Declare it above the for loop like `links = ''` and your error should go away.

```
for row in tablebodies:
    ...
    links = ''
    for list in rpslide:
        links = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[2]").text
    print(CompanyName , links)
```

Also, if `links` prints empty, you need to figure out why `rpslide` is empty, probably -

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('rpSlide').find_elements_by_css_selecto
```

did not find anything

Comment: That's why I said `in your code` but I'll demonstrate that, editing

Comment: @Inder could you see i have posted one more code below for the same error.

Comment: @ThatBird could you see i have posted one more code below for the same error

Comment: @sachinsafale that is not an answer. Edit your question, add the snippet there

Comment: @ThatBird Done Can you help me out